# Why all values are not Dynamically Passed in Html using Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I use vue js with laravel.

I pass multiple variables threw vuejs component(template), i can pass few variables successfully.

But few of them not passed, shows Empty("").

**HTML**  (Template):

```
 <template v-if="showTemplate" id="segment_body">
    <div class="col-md-2" align="center">
      <b>Grid</b><br>
      <a href=javascript:void(0) @click="t_showList=false"><i class=""></i>Grid</a> |
      <a href=javascript:void(0) @click="t_showList=true"><i class=""></i>List</a>
    </div>
    <b>ID : @{{ t_id }}</b><br>
    <b>LIST : @{{ t_showList }}</b>
</template>
```

**HTML** (Data Source):

```
<script> var a = { list: false} </script>

 <div>
    <campaign_segment :t_id=1 :t_showList="a.list"></campaign_segment>
 </div>
```

**VueJS** :

```
Vue.component('campaign_segment', {
      template: '#segment_body',
      props: ['t_showList','t_id']
 });
```

**OUPUT** :

```
 ID : 1
 LIST :
```

If i click Option "Grid",

**OUTPUT** :

```
 ID: 1
 LIST : False
```

Why I'm not get the value of list?

Why I only get the value of ID ?

Any other solutions ?

Comment: Are you sure `a` has data populated and `a.list` has what you want?

Comment: Now i update the source.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into this issue because you're you're trying to pass in the javascript object directly to the component instead of passing it through the Vue instance.

Check out this bin: http://jsbin.com/fosifo/edit?html,js,output

The only real difference in the bin is that rather than trying to pass `a` to the component directly here (which won't work b/c the vue instance isn't aware of the data):

```
<script> var a = { list: false} </script>

<div>
    <campaign_segment :t_id=1 :t_showList="a.list"></campaign_segment>
</div>
```

We pass it in through the vue instance:

In your html:

```
<script>
    var a = {list: false}
</script>
```

In your javascript:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        a: a // the `a` value here is referencing that same `var a = {list: false}` in your markup.
    }
})
```

By doing it this way, as the vue instance is being created it's able to bind it's `a` data property to the globally defined variable `a` from your markup.

It's essentially the same as doing this:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        a: {list: false}
    }
})
```